# Getting "null" value from map

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, hashmap

I have HashMap:

```
Map<String, Object> second = new HashMap<>(Map.of("timeout", 20, "verbose", null, "host", "test"));
```

And the second map with no null value. I put their .keyset() to Set and then starting parse.
And when i`m trying to parse it:

```
 if (firstMap.containsKey(s) && secondMap.containsKey(s) && !Objects.equals(firstMap.get(s), secondMap.get(s))) {
            diffList.add(Map.of(s, "changed", "oldValue", firstMap.get(s), "newValue", secondMap.get(s)));
        }
```

I get NPE. I understand why, but i cant understand how i can fix that. I saw similar posts, but it doesnt help me.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.base/java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:208)
at java.base/java.util.ImmutableCollections$MapN.<init>(ImmutableCollections.java:1186)
at java.base/java.util.Map.of(Map.java:1351)
at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:13)
```

Comment: @LuckyBandit74 The initial capacity is not the same as the size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Map.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#of(K,V,K,V,K,V)) does not allow `null` values. To quote the Javadoc:

> **Unmodifiable Maps**
>
> They disallow `null` keys and values. Attempts to create them with null keys or values result in `NullPointerException`.

Instead, you can directly call `put`.

```java
Map<String, Object> second = new HashMap<>();  // `HashMap` permits null values and null key.
second.put("timeout", 20);
second.put("verbose", null);
second.put("host", "test");
```

Comment: I`m sorry, but what if i use Jackson library to pull map with values and then i got this problem? How can i fix that?

Comment: I mean, i can`t pick in which way ObjectMapper will put values in my Map. So how can i fix that?

Comment: @zxcfawn You should post a *new* Question on that specific issue (after searching thoroughly first). This Answer addresses the Question asked.

Answer (score 0):

`Map.of` doesn't allow for neither `null` keys nor `null` values. If I got your code correctly, you will eventually handle the key `verbose` which has a `null` value in your map `second`.

references:

- [Javadoc Map.of](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#of--)
- [Immutable Map factory method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#immutable)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the stacktrace, the maps are ImmutableCollections and null values are not supported in ImmutableCollections.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/core/creating-immutable-lists-sets-and-maps.htm#JSCOR-GUID-1222F8A3-7EC0-4E49-9B75-C3B263F9A1BB

Answer (score 0):

The Map.of() and Map.ofEntries() static factory methods provide a convenient way to create immutable maps. The Map instances created by these methods have the following characteristics:

...
They disallow null keys and values. Attempts to create them with null keys or values result in NullPointerException.